# How was Prince Cavin established on Earth?

Tags: wildfire

In this mid-'80s Hanna-Barbera cartoon... there are some inconsistencies:

**Wildfire** is a magical talking horse in service to the royal family of Darshaan; whether that's just the *country* or the world *itself* is never made clear. In Darshaan magic exists, animals can talk, and apparently an attempted coup took place some years before....

Queen Sarana is near death due to a curse by sorceress, Lady Diabolyn. She entrusts her magical amulet (given to her as a betrothal present by her disappeared husband, Prince Cavin) and baby daughter, the princess Sara, to Wildfire to take to the "Mortal world," a.k.a. Earth, to escape the curse. Fast forward 12 years:

Sara is a tomboyish preteen who adventures in Darshaan with Wildfire, often disappearing with her adoptive single-parent farmer father *none* the wiser. This is a necessity: as Crown Princess, Sarah has to learn to govern Darhsaan, proving to the humans and magical creatures alike that she can take her mother's place as queen one day. All the while she has to stop the "evil" (honestly, its more like petty mischievous to *occasionally* criminal) actions of Diabolyn, and odd one-of threats, all **without** just using the more pragmatic approach of taking up arms, Narnia-style, and *wrecking* the witch's rear to simplify the situation.

Here's the nonsense part, though:

John Cavanaugh is *somehow* also Prince Cavin, her **natural father.**

Wildfire brought *him* to Earth sometime before to "escape Diaoblyn's curse".

Now, presuming Sara was a newborn on the night Wildfire left her with John, there's still some stuff that doesn't make sense:

- We know from a time travel episode that John and Saranah were together for a *year* after their wedding before the curse took effect. So, Wildfire likely then had to bring John to earth while his queen was pregnant. Why didn't they use that time to find some way to *break the curse?*
- Apparently Wildfire has been keeping a watch on Sara since she was a little girl. She has friends in Darshaan, but is likely not yet old enough to be Queen...okay, fine; her powers are limited until then. However, Diabolyn has attacked the kingdom and **kidnapped fairies** at least *once!* So why has the interim government *not* taken her out as a criminal yet?
- John has **no memory** of his life on Darshaan. Okay, fine; but then *how*, if he was a prince before, and they had *no connections* in our world, did he manage to have a farm, a life and an *established human identity* here that baby Sara could just "slip in" to?

*Note:* He got his memories back for a short time due to the magic of the amulet, which Sara placed in his care when she was essentially kidnapped.

I know this is an '80s cartoon, but honestly, some of the *basics* of it just don't make sense. As I don't think it got a proper finale or second season, a *lot* is open to speculation, so I'm wondering if anyone else has some clarity on these things that I might have missed, or if there was some follow up I'm not privy to. Feel free to add it here, please.

Comment: Can you slim this down a bit? It looks fascinating, but its length makes it a little difficult to follow. If you cut out some of the summary and analysis or opinions, and focus on the central question, I think the answer quality will be higher.

Comment: Appreciated. It's a relatively *obscure* cartoon, though; I wanted to give some context to those totally unfamiliar. Buzz answered the question quite well, though; these were queries I had as a kid, and simply wondered if no one else saw them, or if I missed something because, as a boy and more into action toons, I was only half paying attention to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could tell you that there was some cogent explanation for what was going on, but there simply wasn't.  This was obvious to the child viewers at the time (at least the slightly older ones of us; I can't speak for my younger sibling).  This is hardly unique to *Wildfire*; in the 1980s there were a whole slew of children's cartoons involving characters with magical or science fiction secrets that made no sense if you took a few minutes and tried to puzzle them out (*[Mighty Orbots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Orbots)*, *[Little Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Wizards)*, etc.).

So unless there were some other key plot elements that were only described on the toy horse packaging (which was about all there was in the way of additional media for the short-lived *Wildfire* show), there was just no explanation of how any of this stuff made sense.